# Changing url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP url shortener script that redirects the user from a URL such as http://domain.com/go.php?url=**5DIGITID** but I want it to instead be a URL like the following; http://domain.com/**5DIGITID**

There are no other directories or folders in the domain.

**How can I make my .htaccess files call go.php?url=ID?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Once you've done that, try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ go.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @CosmoPosmo drop the leading slash `/` i.e. `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ go.php?url=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: @CosmoPosmo is your ID all numeric or is it alphanumeric. If the latter, change rule to `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ go.php?url=$1 [NC,L]`.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed **5DIGITID** meant an ID consisting of five digits.